# Nginx Direct Server Return for UDP

Tags: linux, nginx, udp, load-balancing, traffic

I'm using this resource (https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/) to setup a UDP load balancer, with DSR and Origin NAT.

Everything went fine in the walkthrough until I reached the traffic control stuff :

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 10: htb
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 u32 match ip src 172.16.0.11 match ip sport 53 action nat egress 172.16.0.11 192.168.99.10
```

The second command fails with :

```
Illegal "match"
```

From what I can read here (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-u32.8.html), the syntax looks correct though.
Of course I replaced 172.16.0.11 with the actual IP of the upstream I'm configuring, and 192.168.99.10 with the IP of the host hosting the Nginx. The interface name is eth0.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS.

Is the "tc filter" command incorrect, or am I doing something wrong ? Would it be simpler with IPVS ?

Thank you !

Comment: Illegal match should probably mean an issue with the IP i believe

Comment: Recompiling and instrumenting the tc binary, I found out that the match sport requires a port number and a bitmask. The ip part works properly though. I didn't found what the bitmask exactly is, didn't found the information in the man pages of tc-u32. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the 0xffff mask for accepting all the range.

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 u32 match ip src 172.16.0.11 match ip sport 53 0xffff action nat egress 172.16.0.11 192.168.99.10
```

Comment: Pff, how come I didn't try this before ! Thank you !